# Adding Javascript to PHP File With HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php file with php code that fetches data from mysql table and displays it in a table. The table contains delete links. To prevent accidental deletion, I added a javascript alert to the delete link. But the javascript does not show the alert dialog box.

below is the picture of the page 
[image]

From the picture above , the  user is expected to be prompted when they click the delete link.

below is my code.

```
<? php
include('/templates/header.php');
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "root"; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "datacentre"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "data_centre_users"; // Table name 
$server_name = "localhost";

// Create connection
$con = new mysqli($server_name, $username, $password, $db_name, 3306);
if ($con - > connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: ".$con - > connect_error);
}

// Check connection
if ($con - > connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: ".$conn - > connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE status <> 'approved' ";
$result = $con - > query($sql);


?>

< section id = "sidebar" >

  < /section>

<section id="content">

<div id="scroll-table">
<table >
<caption>
           List data from mysql
            </caption >
  < tr >
  < th class = "center" > < strong > Name < /strong></th >
  < th class = "center" > < strong > Request < /strong></th >
  < th class = "center" > < strong > Purpose < /strong></th >
  < th class = "center" > < strong > Description < /strong></th >
  < th class = "center" > < strong > Approve < /strong></th >
  < th class = "center" > < strong > Delete < /strong></th >
  < /tr>
            <?php
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                / / output data of each row
while ($rows = $result - > fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  < tr >
    < td class = "center" > <? php echo $rows['first_name']; ?> < /td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['request']; ?></td >
  < td class = "center" > <? php echo $rows['purpose']; ?> < /td>
                        <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['description']; ?></td >
  < td class = "center" > < a href = "approve.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"
  onclick = "return confirm("
  Ae u sure ");" > approve < /a></td >
    < td class = "center" > < a href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"
  onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');" > delete < /a></td >
    < /tr>

                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?> 
</table >
    < /div>
</section >

<?php
$con->close();

include('/templates / footer.php ');
?>
```

Comment: Look into the html source code and make sure the code is fine. Also look into the browser's console and keep your eyes open for errors.

Comment: Are you taking the michael faisal. Does that page actually show on the browser?

Comment: Just want to use a javascript alert dialog for the delete link. there is a piece of javascript code in the delete row.

Comment: Are you not seeing the dialogue? Unless your php is not outputting valid html that should be working. Do you have an example page anywhere we can see?

Comment: I have just added the picture of the page

Comment: For starters please remove all the extra spaces. `< tr >` is not a valid html tag, and `class = ""` is not a valid attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<a href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')){ location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>'; }">delete</a>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but can you explain the logic to me.

Comment: basically it does a logic within href, by calling javascript:. Then the if confirm is true (by clicking yes), it execute location.href. Otherwise, nothing happens.